# Is this second order D.E. is solvable

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
DSolve[{(2.248*10^12) x^2  y''[x] + (4.496 x - 50.535)*10^12 y'[
x] - (1.17977*10^32) (x^3 Exp[-2 x] y[x] == 0, y[10] == 10^-5.3},
y[x], x]
```

You can use b.c. `y[0]==10^-5.3` and Plot Range `{x,10,100},{y,10^-4,10^-15}`and Log Plot this

Comment: There is a typo in your ode, missing paranthese near y[x]. You should provide two b.c. and increase WorkingPrecision to get a meaningful result.

Comment: Are you seeking a symbolic or numerical solution?  If seeking a numerical solution, use `NDSolve` instead of `DSolve`.  I am not optimistic that a closed form symbolic solution exists.